# Django cache 2 different versions of a url (JSON & HTML)

Tags: python, django, caching

I have one url, lets say /users/comments/. This page can be accessed with HTML or with JSON via ajax.

I want to cache both version of the page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an easy way to do it. But this is the code to manually cache and return the JSON copy of the site if the GET params ?type=json otherwise will return the html.

Top of view:

```
if request.GET.get('type', None) == 'json' and not request.user.is_authenticated():
    #check cache
    cached_page = cache.get(request.get_full_path())
    if cached_page:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(cached_page), content_type="application/json")
```

At the bottom of view:

```
if request.is_ajax():

    rendered = render_to_string('lootr/deal-item.html', params, context)

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        cache.set(request.get_full_path(), rendered, 60 * 30)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(rendered), content_type="application/json")
```